# Get String before/after String.indexof in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have this text :

> <Parag1>Data-tier applications can be used to work with existing databases, or they can be used to implement new projects and releases.
>
> To get started, it is recommended that you create data-tier applications from existing systems by registering each production database as a data-tier application.</Parag1>
>
> <Parag2>Then, users can extract each database to produce a DAC package and send the packages to the development team.</Parag2>
>
> <Parag3>From there on, developers use Visual Studio to author data-tier changes, package them appropriately, and forward the updated DAC packages to production.</Parag3>
>
> <Pagag4>In turn, DBAs can upgrade the production applications using automatic methods and tools that are provided by the data-tier application framework.</Parag4>

I need to extract the text from 'with existing databases' in paragraph 1 to 'each database to produce' in paragraph 2.

How can I get this result in c# with the following inputs:

```
start paragraph : p1

Start character index : 43
/* index of w in 'with' */

Finish paragraph : p2

Finish character index : 47
/* index of e in 'produce' */
```

Comment: You want to extract the following "with existing databases, or they can be used to implement new projects and releases.

To get started, it is recommended that you create data-tier applications from existing systems by registering each production database as a data-tier application. < /Parag1 >

< Parag2 >Then, users can extract each database to produce" into a new string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to preserve the paragraph separation, or do you just need the text?
If the paragraphs are irrelevant, I would load this XML snippet into an XmlDocument object, merge the texts into a single string, and then just use normal string manipulation to extract.

```
 var snippet = //your text here.
 var rawXml = "<text>" + snippet + "</text>"; // Wrap to make valid XML.
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.LoadXml(rawXml);
 var mergedText = xmlDoc.InnerText;
 int start = mergedText.IndexOf(startMarker);
 int end = mergedText.IndexOf(endMarker) - start;
 mergedText.Substring(start, end);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = text.IndexOf("with existing databases");
int i2 = text.IndexOf("each database to produce");
int l = "each database to produce".Length;
string substring = text.Substring(i, i2 - i + l);
```